# How to keep the same link for a file on Wix

Tags: html, redirect, hyperlink, velo

I've a client who have an website created with Wix. And we work together to implement a qrcode link who redirect on a file in the website. It's for restaurant menus.
But we have a problem, when he make an uppgrade of the file, Wix generate a new link for the file and this breaks my redirection by qrcode.

How it's possible to create a same link with the same name for all uppgrade of the file ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.